# Eliminate list entries lacking sublist matches?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a very large list called `runlist` which includes multiple sublists. `runlist` is in the form of `[[ ], [ ], [ ], ...]` where each entry is like this:

```
print runlist[1]
[['632', '143', '11'], ['633', '143', '9'], ['422', '144', '5'], ['628', '144', '8'], ['629', '144', '12'], ['630', '144', '12'], ['631', '144', '10'], ['632', '144', '9'], ['633', '144', '6'], ['629', '145', '8'], ['630', '145', '8'], ['631', '145', '8'], ['632', '145', '8'], ['632', '146', '5']]
```

But each entry has different numbers. I'd like to have my code find all `runlist[i]` entries where the first entry of the sublists (the x-coordinates if you will) has to fall in a certain range just once. But I have multiple different number ranges, where each have to match at least one x-coordinate in the `runlist[i]` list. In other words, I want to check if each `runlist[i]` has a number between 600-649 in any of the x-entries (`runlist[i][j][0]`), AND at least one number that falls between 400-449 in any other `runlist[i][j][0]`. This is for the same `i`, but any `j`. Then I'd like to save all matching `runlist[i]` lists in a new list called `goodrunslist`.

Here's what I've tried, but it's giving me `goodrunslist` as an empty list at the end -- probably because it's trying to match those number ranges for each `runlist[i][j][0]`, instead of just any one. What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

```
import re
goodrunslist = []
for i in range(len(runlist)):
    for j in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[4][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][j][0]) and re.match('[6][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][j][0]):
            goodrunslist.append(runlist[i])
```

Update: I've now tried the below code instead which I thought would work, but I'm still getting an empty list.

```
for i in range(len(runlist)):
    for j in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[6][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][j][0]):
            ch1 = True
        else:
            ch1 = False
    for k in range (0, len(runlist[i])):
        if re.match('[4][0-4][0-9]', runlist[i][k][0]):
            ch2 = True
        else:
            ch2 = False
    if ch1 and ch2:
        goodrunslist.append(runlist[i])
```

Comment: So you're just trying to ensure the first value is in the range of 400-449 or 600-649

Comment: But just any one of the first values has to be in each of those ranges. For example, `[['633', '143', '9'], ['422', '144', '5'], ['343', '244', '2']]` should be considered a match, but `[['633', '143', '9'], ['582', '144', '5'], ['343', '244', '2']]` should not.

Comment: How come the first one is a match if `343` is out of range?

Comment: Because all that matters is that there's at least one in the sublists that matches in each range. Since 633 matches the first range and 422 matches the second range, I want this list to be considered a match.

Comment: Well that's fine, but then why should the second not match? It has `633` in it.

Comment: Because the second one only matches one of the ranges -- I want there to be at least one match for each range specified.

Comment: But then the first one doesn't satisfy this since the third range in the first set includes `343`, `244`, `2`

Comment: Each list is like `[[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ...]`. I need at least one of the many `xi` values to fall in range1 (600-649), and one of the many `xi` values to fall in range2 (300-349). The rest of them don't matter, as long as I have at least one match per numerical range.

Comment: Oh, so you need each set to contain one `x` in the range of `600-649` and `x` in the range `400-449`?

Comment: Yes! Do you know an efficient way to go about that?

Comment: Yes, but what is the value that you're trying to obtain at the end? I'm currently getting true/false values, but not sure what output you're seeking. Or are you trying to remove what doesn't match those ranges?

Comment: Basically, does [this](https://tio.run/##lc3BCsMgEATQe75ibhshB6tbQWi@RDwESqhQTLAWkq@3MfbQay878Bhm1z0/lqhLSe/4DK@MEc6R0ZoG0IXPsOQHOGKlGnKNa0PdKqqhIu@7bk0h5n6Ke79hXhI2hAhXLTjpxWmh2venR5jBUuI2Ht3jMFsITPGOP0fMz4hhK0QpHw) work for you?